# Strikethrough in google apps script based on a condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an object.

```
{ C43: 'X13',
  C59: 'X13',
  C75: 'X14',
  C91: 'X14',
  C107: 'X16',
  C123: 'X17',
  C139: 'X17' }
```

Here, the keys of the object in an ordered manner are the cells where some data is present.

I want to identify where the same value repeats of one or more keys and strikethrough that row.

So, in the above object, `X17` value is same for the keys `C123` and `C139`. I want whichever is earlier/smaller key value's row to be striked through.

So here, strike through row `123`as is belongs to `C123` which is the smallest/earlier entry than `C139`.

Please help!
Thank you

Comment: Does the object represent the actual spreadsheet or just an example? Is C123 the actual Cell or just a random key?

Comment: Thank you @CharlesHan, It is an actual cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for your ideas. You need to replace the sheet name with yours. Let me know if it works in your spreadsheet.

```
function strikeThroughDuplicates(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Example"); //replace your sheet name

  var example = { C43: 'X13',
                  C59: 'X13',
                  C48: 'X14',
                  C50: 'X14',
                  C107: 'X16',
                  C123: 'X17',
                  C139: 'X17' };

  var valueCellsDict = {};
  
  //turn the object to a dictionary as value : cells
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(example)) 
  {
    if(value in valueCellsDict){
      valueCellsDict[value].push(key);
    } else {
      valueCellsDict[value] = [key];
    }
  }

  for(var key in valueCellsDict){
    //loop through the dictionary and only checks value has more than one cells
    if(valueCellsDict[key].length > 1) {
      //loop through cells and strike out cells except the last one.
      for(var index =0; index < valueCellsDict[key].length - 1; index++) {
         var cellPos = valueCellsDict[key][index];
         var cell = targetSheet.getRange(cellPos);
         cell.setFontLine("line-through");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Charles Han, I incorporated the above code , it executes without any error but the strike through did not happen

Comment: @AliciaStone You might want to share your code and an example spreadsheet. I've uploaded the result spreadsheet from my example.

Comment: Let me try that again, sure let me share the code

Comment: Doesn't this strike through the wrong entries? The question seems to suggest that all duplicates _except_ the last one should be struck. The code however strikes the last one and leaves other duplicates be. It also does not seem to work with non-consecutive duplicates.

Comment: @doubleunary yes, you were right. I have fixed the issues, and it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

To find if a value is a duplicate, but not the last one to appear in the list, use `Array.filter()` and `Array.lastIndexOf()`, like this:

```js
function test() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const cellValueObject = {
    C43: 'X13',
    C59: 'X13',
    C75: 'X14',
    C91: 'X14',
    C107: 'X16',
    C123: 'X17',
    C139: 'X17',
    C991: 'X14', // test non-consecutive duplicate values
  };
  const dupCellsA1 = getKeysOfDuplicateValuesExceptLast(cellValueObject);
  const dupRowsA1 = getRowReferenceA1FromCellA1(dupCellsA1);
  const rowList = sheet.getRangeList(dupRowsA1);
  rowList.setFontLine('line-through');
}

function getKeysOfDuplicateValuesExceptLast(object) {
  const values = Object.values(object);
  return Object.keys(object).filter((_, index) =>
    index !== values.lastIndexOf(values[index])
  );
}

function getRowReferenceA1FromCellA1(cellsA1) {
  return cellsA1.map(rangeA1 => {
    const rowNumber = rangeA1.replace(/[^\d]/, '');
    return `A${rowNumber}:${rowNumber}`;
  });
}
```

`rowList` is a `RangeList` object. Formatting a `RangeList` is much more efficient that formatting individual `Range` objects one by one.